# Question about optimization in a non usual framework

Tags: calculus, optimization

In game theory I encounter the following optimization problem :

Find the infinimum of $f(y)=4yx-x-2y$ where $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Usual first order derivative result cannot be used here. However, when I take the derivative with respect to $y$ I find a value for $x$, namely $x=1/2$.

Conversely, if I consider $f(x)= 4yx-x-2y$, the first order derivative test gives me $y=1/4$.

I wonder what it can represent to find a value for a « parameter » ? Is there a link with a possible solution to the basic optimization problem of finding a minimum or a maximum ? My former intuition on the slope of the tangent does not seem to help me a lot here.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you asking how can you determine whether the point where the first order derivatives are 0 is a minimum or maximum?

Comment: @jet457 Yes given the fact that the point we get at the first order derivative tells us the value of $x$ when we derive w.r.t $y$ and vice versa , it seems that the answer should be no but I would like to know if there is something I ignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in finding the minimum of your function, you can test whether the point you found by checking where the gradient (that is $\pmatrix{\partial_x f & \partial_y f}$) is 0 (in your case $(1/2, 1/4)$) is a minimum or maximum by using the second derivative test. In multivariable calculus, the test involves checking if the Hessian matrix is

- positive definite ($\Rightarrow$ local minimum)
- negative definite ($\Rightarrow$ local maximum)
- positive semidefinite (could be local max, local min, or saddle)
- negative semidefinite (could be local max, local min, or saddle)
- none of the above (in which case it must be saddle)

The definitions for these properties can be found on [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix). More details on the multivariable second derivative test can be found on [KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/applications-of-multivariable-derivatives/optimizing-multivariable-functions/a/second-partial-derivative-test) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test). This is a generalization of the second derivative test for one variable, where you check to see if the second derivative is positive or negative at your point in question.

In your case, computing the Hessian, you get the matrix
$$\pmatrix{\partial_x^2 f & \partial_x \partial_y f \\ \partial_y\partial_x f & \partial_y^2 f} = \pmatrix{0 & 4 \\ 4 & 0}.$$
You can check this matrix falls in the *none of the above* case since
$$\pmatrix{1 & 1} \pmatrix{0 & 4 \\ 4 & 0} \pmatrix{1 \\ 1} = 8$$
and
$$\pmatrix{1 & -1} \pmatrix{0 & 4 \\ 4 & 0} \pmatrix{1 \\ -1} = -8$$
So the point the first derivative test found is a saddle point.

Since there is only one point where the gradient is $0$, this tells you the minimum must be on the boundary of your domain. You can check pretty easily that

- if $x = 0$, then your function is $-2y$ which is minimized to $-2$ at $y=1$
- if $x = 1$, then your function is $2y - 1$ which is minimized to $-1$ at $y=0$
- if $y=0$, then your function is $-x$ which is minimized to $-1$ at $x=1$
- if $y=1$, then your function is $3x-2$ which is minimized to $-2$ at $x = 0$.

So the minimum of your function is $-2$ at $(0, 1)$.